# Listing my Azure permissions from Azure Java SDK

Tags: java, azure, azure-java-sdk

There is Azure API for listing my own permissions. It's partially documented in [Azure API Permissions doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/authorization/permissions) (thought they miss the per-subscription case in documentation).

I am struggling to find a way how to call this API via [Azure Java SDK](https://github.com/Azure/azure-libraries-for-java) - there is [Access Management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.azure.resourcemanager.accessmanagement?view=azure-java-stable) interface accessible via `.accessManagement()` method, but that contains methods for listing roles and role assignments, not for listing the actual permissions.

Is this missing from the SDK or am I just searching badly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes Azure SDK lacks some functionality. And I also checked the java SDK source seems there is no such interface to call this API directly.

So you have 2 options here:

**1.** Get the role assignments so that you can get the actual role ID, use this role ID you can get the role actual permissions by code below:

```
        Set<Permission> permissions = azureResourceManager.accessManagement().roleDefinitions().getById(
                        "{role id}")
                        .permissions();
```

**2.** Call the REST API directly, just try the code below:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import com.azure.core.credential.TokenCredential;
import com.azure.core.credential.TokenRequestContext;
import com.azure.core.management.AzureEnvironment;
import com.azure.core.management.profile.AzureProfile;
import com.azure.identity.ClientSecretCredentialBuilder;
import com.google.gson.Gson;

public class testAzureAPI {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        AzureProfile azureProfile = new AzureProfile(AzureEnvironment.AZURE);
        //I use ClientSecretCredential just for demo here, you can change it your self
        TokenCredential tokenCredential = new ClientSecretCredentialBuilder()
                .clientId("").clientSecret("")
                .tenantId("")  
   .authorityHost(azureProfile.getEnvironment().getActiveDirectoryEndpoint()).build();

        String accessToken = tokenCredential
                .getToken(new TokenRequestContext().addScopes("https://management.azure.com/.default")).block()
                .getToken();

        String reqURL = "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourcegroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/permissions?api-version=2015-07-01";

        try {

            URL url = new URL(reqURL);
            URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine = in.lines().collect(Collectors.joining());
            in.close();

            Permissions perms = new Gson().fromJson(inputLine, Permissions.class);

            System.out.println(perms.getValue().get(2).getActions());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public class Value {
        public List<String> actions;

        public List<Object> notActions;

        public List<String> getActions() {
            return actions;
        }

        public void setActions(List<String> actions) {
            this.actions = actions;
        }

        public List<Object> getNotActions() {
            return notActions;
        }

        public void setNotActions(List<Object> notActions) {
            this.notActions = notActions;
        }
    }

    public class Permissions {
        public List<Value> value;

        public List<Value> getValue() {
            return value;
        }

        public void setValue(List<Value> value) {
            this.value = value;
        }
    }
}
```

I have tested on my side and it works for me perfectly:

**Result:**
By API:
[image]

By code:
[image]

Comment: Thanks @Stanley Gong for the exhaustive answer with detailed alternative, which is even more than I asked for. I will wait couple days in case magically someone finds this in the SDK and then I will accept your answer.

Comment: @Michal no prob buddy :)